# How to show only pieces of hidden text with jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have an html file with a calendar and a bunch of "Today in Weather History" info.  I want to hide all of the weather history until someone clicks on a particular day on the calendar, then I want to reveal only the history for that day.

The daily weather info is hidden, but it will not show the particular day when it's calendar day is clicked.  I'm assuming I'm going about this all wrong.  Better ways to about it would be appreciated.

Calendar day link:

```
<td align="right"><a id="c0408" href="#"> 8</a></td>
```

Weather History:

```
<div id="allhistory">
  <div id="hc0408" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li class="dateheader">April 8, 2007</li>
      <li>The Savannah Airport drops to 28 degrees, its lowest April 
          temperature.</li>
      <li class="dateheader">April 8, 2007</li>
      <li>Summerville has their coldest April temperature, when the mercury 
          falls to 27 degrees.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="hc0409" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li class="dateheader">April 9, 2011</li>
      <li>Severe thunderstorms impact Berkeley County in South Carolina, 
          with hail as large as tennis balls (2.5 inches) and winds as 
          high as 64 mph.</li>
    </ul> <!-- 0409 -->
  </div>
</div> <!-- all history div -->
```

The jQuery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#calendar a').click(function() {
      var dateid = $(this).attr('id');
      var selection = "div#h"+dateid;
      $("selection").show();
     })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "p#h" <- Do you mean div#h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#calendar a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#allhistory [id^="h"]').hide();
      $('#h'+$(this).attr('id')).css('display','inline-block');
     })
});
```

Comment: Great! That worked. Now I just need to hide what's there if the user clicks on another date.

Comment: @user2208943 Are you want , after that he click another day you want to hide the old one and show the day just pressed?

Answer (score 0):

concatenate the id and show the respective jquery object

try this

```
$('#calendar a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();  //to prevent the default behaviour of a
  var dateid = $(this).attr('id');
  var selection = $("#h"+dateid); //assign selection as jquery object
  selection.show(); //show it
  .....
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("selection").show();`

This is your problem. You are providing the string "selection" as a selector. You want to provide the variable; like this:

`$(selection).show();`